# Unable to create VNet using JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have the below script, whch is a section of a script I'm using to deploy a vnet. However it fails to create a the vnet, any idea where I might be going wrong?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "client": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Client name - max 3 chars"
      }
    },
    "environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Environment name - max 3 chars"
      }
    },
    "businessUnit": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Business Unit name - max 3 chars"
      }
    },
    "appName": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "App name - max 3 chars"
      }
    },
    "addressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The address space in CIDR notation for the new virtual network."
      }
    },
    "subnetName1": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the first subnet in the new virtual network."
      }
    },
    "subnetName2": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the first subnet in the new virtual network."
      }
    },
    "gatewaySubnet": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "GatewaySubnet",
      "allowedValues": [
        "GatewaySubnet"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the subnet where Gateway is to be deployed. This must always be named GatewaySubnet."
      }
    },
    "subnetPrefix1": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The address range in CIDR notation for the first subnet."
      }
    },
    "subnetPrefix2": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The address range in CIDR notation for the first subnet."
      }
    },
    "gatewaySubnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The address range in CIDR notation for the Gateway subnet. For ExpressRoute enabled Gateways, this must be minimum of /28."
      }
    },
    "dnsServerAddress": {
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
        "Description": "The DNS address(es) of the DNS Server(s) used by the VNET"
      }
    },
    "dnsServerAddressUpdateDns": {
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
        "Description": "The DNS address(es) of the DNS Server(s) used by the VNET"
      }
    },
    "vpnClientAddressPoolPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The IP address range from which VPN clients will receive an IP address when connected. Range specified must not overlap with on-premise network."
      }
    },
    "vmMfaName1privateIPAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The IP address of the MFA server."
      }
    },
    "vmMfaName2privateIPAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The IP address of the MFA server."
      }
    },
    "vmMfaLbIpAddress1": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The IP address of the RADIUS server."
      }
    },
    "radiusServerSecret": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The secret of the RADIUS server."
      }
    },
    "omsWorkSpaceResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Workspace Resource Group"
      }
    },
    "omsWorkSpaceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Workspace Resource Name"
      }
    },
    "omsWorkspaceStorageAccount": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account of OMS Workspace"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "vnetApiVersion": "2017-10-01",
    "virtualNetworkPeeringApiVersion": "2017-10-01",
    "routeTableApiVersion": "2017-10-01",
    "locksApiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "virtualNetworkName": "[tolower(concat('vnet-', parameters('client'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', parameters('businessUnit'), '-', parameters('appName')))]",
    "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "gatewaySubnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',parameters('gatewaySubnet'))]",
    "virtualNetworkGatewayName": "[tolower(concat('vng-', parameters('client'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', parameters('businessUnit'), '-', parameters('appName')))]",
    "gatewaySku": "vpngw1",
    "gatewayPublicIPName": "[tolower(concat('pip-', parameters('client'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', parameters('businessUnit'), '-', parameters('appName')))]",
    "vpnClientProtocols": "IkeV2",
    "subnetName1": "[tolower(concat('sub-', parameters('client'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', parameters('businessUnit'), '-', parameters('appName'), '-', parameters('subnetName1')))]",
    "routeTable1": "[tolower(concat('udr-', variables('subnetName1')))]",
    "networkSecurityGroup1": "[tolower(concat('nsg-', variables('subnetName1')))]",
    "subnetName2": "[tolower(concat('sub-', parameters('client'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', parameters('businessUnit'), '-', parameters('appName'), '-', parameters('subnetName2')))]",
    "routeTable2": "[tolower(concat('udr-', variables('subnetName2')))]",
    "networkSecurityGroup2": "[tolower(concat('nsg-', variables('subnetName2')))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('routeTable1')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('routeTableApiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "routes": [
        ],
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": false
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('routeTable2')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('routeTableApiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "routes": [
        ],
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": false
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroup1')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', variables('routeTable1'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "AllowInboundAnyAddressSpace",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 100,
              "protocol": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "*"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "AllowInboundHttpsMfaServer1",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 101,
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('vmMfaName1privateIPAddress')]",
              "destinationPortRange": "443"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "AllowInboundHttpsMfaServer2",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 102,
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('vmMfaName2privateIPAddress')]",
              "destinationPortRange": "443"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "AllowOutboundAnyAddressSpace",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 100,
              "protocol": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Outbound",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
              "destinationPortRange": "*"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "microsoft.network/networksecuritygroups/providers/diagnosticSettings",
      "name": "[concat(variables('networkSecurityGroup1'), '/Microsoft.Insights/service')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networksecuritygroups/', variables('networkSecurityGroup1'))]"
      ],
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "name": "service",
        "storageAccountId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('omsWorkSpaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('omsWorkspaceStorageAccount'))]",
        "workspaceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('omsWorkSpaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('omsWorkSpaceName'))]",
        "logs": [
          {
            "category": "NetworkSecurityGroupEvent",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 365,
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          {
            "category": "NetworkSecurityGroupRuleCounter",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 365,
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroup2')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', variables('routeTable2'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "AllowInboundAnyAddressSpace",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 100,
              "protocol": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "*"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "AllowOutboundAnyAddressSpace",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 100,
              "protocol": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Outbound",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
              "destinationPortRange": "*"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "microsoft.network/networksecuritygroups/providers/diagnosticSettings",
      "name": "[concat(variables('networkSecurityGroup2'), '/Microsoft.Insights/service')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networksecuritygroups/', variables('networkSecurityGroup2'))]"
      ],
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "name": "service",
        "storageAccountId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('omsWorkSpaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('omsWorkspaceStorageAccount'))]",
        "workspaceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('omsWorkSpaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('omsWorkSpaceName'))]",
        "logs": [
          {
            "category": "NetworkSecurityGroupEvent",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 365,
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          {
            "category": "NetworkSecurityGroupRuleCounter",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 365,
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('vnetApiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', variables('routeTable1'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', variables('routeTable2'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networksecuritygroups/', variables('networkSecurityGroup1'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networksecuritygroups/', variables('networkSecurityGroup2'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "dhcpOptions": {
          "dnsServers": "[parameters('dnsServerAddress')]"
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName1')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix1')]",
              "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroup1'))]"
              },
              "routeTable": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', variables('routeTable1'))]"
              },
              "serviceEndpoints": [
                {
                  "service": "Microsoft.Storage",
                  "locations": [
                    "[resourceGroup().location]"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                  "locations": [
                    "[resourceGroup().location]"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName2')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix2')]",
              "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroup2'))]"
              },
              "routeTable": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', variables('routeTable2'))]"
              },
              "serviceEndpoints": [
                {
                  "service": "Microsoft.Storage",
                  "locations": [
                    "[resourceGroup().location]"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                  "locations": [
                    "[resourceGroup().location]"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[parameters('gatewaySubnet')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('gatewaySubnetPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat(variables('virtualNetworkName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', variables('virtualNetworkName'), '-LockDoNotDelete')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/providers/locks",
          "apiVersion": "[variables('locksApiVersion')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "level": "CanNotDelete",
            "notes": "Resource Lock - Do Not Delete!",
            "owners": [
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('gatewayPublicIPName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways",
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkGatewayName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('gatewayPublicIPName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('gatewaySubnetRef')]"
              },
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('gatewayPublicIPName'))]"
              }
            },
            "name": "vnetGatewayConfig"
          }
        ],
        "sku": {
          "name": "[variables('gatewaySku')]",
          "tier": "[variables('gatewaySku')]"
        },
        "gatewayType": "Vpn",
        "vpnType": "RouteBased",
        "enableBgp": "false",
        "vpnClientConfiguration": {
          "vpnClientAddressPool": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
              "[parameters('vpnClientAddressPoolPrefix')]"
            ]
          },
          "vpnClientProtocols": [
            "[variables('vpnClientProtocols')]"
          ],
          "radiusServerAddress": "[parameters('vmMfaLbIpAddress1')]",
          "radiusServerSecret": "[parameters('radiusServerSecret')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is used to create a vnet and subnets before vm's are deployed to it.

I can't see where I'm going wrong, I'm baffled ..Any help would be appreciated  Thanks

Comment: The error will be really helpful to narrow down issue

Comment: Hi the error just says unable to find resource for a vm, the missing resource is the vent and subnets

Comment: The template need lots of information so cannot try deployment.  Most likely problem is you address spaces. Which ones are you using for VNet, Subnets and Gateway

Comment: @Hannel using 10.10.2.0/22 for vnet and subnets 10.10.2.32/27 and 10.10.2.64/27 that’s the ranges I use?

Comment: there is no vm in ths template, paste your EXACT error text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, without you showing the exact error text, its pretty hard to tell what goes wrong exactly, i do have to admit template quality is mediocre. The most common error is wrong dependsOn property. Your typical `dependsOn`:

```
"[concat('Microsoft.Network/networksecuritygroups/', variables('networkSecurityGroup1'))]"
```

Proper `dependsOn`:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networksecuritygroups/', variables('networkSecurityGroup1'))]"
```

You also have lots of places that could be improved, for example, why do you have parameter for gateway subnet name? It always is `gatewaysubnet`. You cannot change it. you are using prefixes for resource types instead of suffixes, you construct resource names in variables section and various other things which are used only once (for the most part) in the template (so just a waste of space). using `concat()` instead of `resourceId()` in many places:

```
"storageAccountId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('omsWorkSpaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('omsWorkspaceStorageAccount'))]",
"storageAccountId": "[resourceId(parameters('omsWorkSpaceResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('omsWorkspaceStorageAccount'))]",
```

second option is almost 2 times shorter...

Comment: Amended the depondsOn, worked a treat, also thanks for the complete answer and tips, always good to get some pointers .. thanks for your help

Comment: Hey I'm really stuck with this json files, is there anything you can do to help, I can't post the full scripts here :(

Comment: create a new question, with a link to something like pastebin.org with your code

Comment: created new question "Json dependsOn ignored" Let me know if yhou need the parameter file too? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw the question was marked as 'answered' this morning so i did post my yesterday finding, but since you are still having issue i will post them.

Yes, the template is not the greatest, seems it was put together by copying bit and piece from different templates.

With that been said i focused on the Network section that you mentioned you have issues with. Extract the network section, tweak a little to make up for missing parameters and variables and tried to deploy it. Noticed 2 issues

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8l92.png]

### Issues

- dnsserveraddress and dnsserveraddressupdatedns parameters had 'type' as array that did not really accepted any valid input.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9QSP.png]

- Also got error that address space CIDR Notation you provided 10.10.2.0/22 is an invalid CIDR Notation.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXWFB.png]

### Resolution

Once i correct both i was able to deploy the network section without any issues

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yzrK.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHaH2.png]

**Tweak JSON i used just to deploy VNet.**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "addressPrefix": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The address space in CIDR notation for the new virtual network."
            }
        },
        "subnetName1": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the first subnet in the new virtual network."
            }
        },
        "subnetName2": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the first subnet in the new virtual network."
            }
        },
        "gatewaySubnet": {
            "defaultValue": "GatewaySubnet",
            "allowedValues": [
                "GatewaySubnet"
            ],
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the subnet where Gateway is to be deployed. This must always be named GatewaySubnet."
            }
        },
        "subnetPrefix1": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The address range in CIDR notation for the first subnet."
            }
        },
        "subnetPrefix2": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The address range in CIDR notation for the first subnet."
            }
        },
        "gatewaySubnetPrefix": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The address range in CIDR notation for the Gateway subnet. For ExpressRoute enabled Gateways, this must be minimum of /28."
            }
        },
        "dnsServerAddress": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "Description": "The DNS address(es) of the DNS Server(s) used by the VNET"
            }
        },
        "dnsServerAddressUpdateDns": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "Description": "The DNS address(es) of the DNS Server(s) used by the VNET"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
        "vnetApiVersion": "2017-10-01",
        "virtualNetworkPeeringApiVersion": "2017-10-01",
        "routeTableApiVersion": "2017-10-01",
        "locksApiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "virtualNetworkName": "[tolower(concat('vnet-Test'))]",
        "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "gatewaySubnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',parameters('gatewaySubnet'))]",
        "subnetName1": "[tolower(concat('sub-', parameters('subnetName1')))]",
        "routeTable1": "[tolower(concat('udr-', variables('subnetName1')))]",
        "networkSecurityGroup1": "[tolower(concat('nsg-', variables('subnetName1')))]",
        "subnetName2": "[tolower(concat('sub-', parameters('subnetName2')))]",
        "routeTable2": "[tolower(concat('udr-', variables('subnetName2')))]",
        "networkSecurityGroup2": "[tolower(concat('nsg-', variables('subnetName2')))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
            "name": "[variables('routeTable1')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('routeTableApiVersion')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "routes": [],
                "disableBgpRoutePropagation": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
            "name": "[variables('routeTable2')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('routeTableApiVersion')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "routes": [],
                "disableBgpRoutePropagation": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroup1')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "AllowInboundAnyAddressSpace",
                        "properties": {
                            "priority": 100,
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "direction": "Inbound",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "AllowOutboundAnyAddressSpace",
                        "properties": {
                            "priority": 100,
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "direction": "Outbound",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', variables('routeTable1'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroup2')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "AllowInboundAnyAddressSpace",
                        "properties": {
                            "priority": 100,
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "direction": "Inbound",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "AllowOutboundAnyAddressSpace",
                        "properties": {
                            "priority": 100,
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "direction": "Outbound",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', variables('routeTable2'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('vnetApiVersion')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
                    ]
                },
                "dhcpOptions": {
                    "dnsServers": "[parameters('dnsServerAddress')]"
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "[variables('subnetName1')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix1')]",
                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroup1'))]"
                            },
                            "routeTable": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', variables('routeTable1'))]"
                            },
                            "serviceEndpoints": [
                                {
                                    "service": "Microsoft.Storage",
                                    "locations": [
                                        "[resourceGroup().location]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                                    "locations": [
                                        "[resourceGroup().location]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "[variables('subnetName2')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix2')]",
                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroup2'))]"
                            },
                            "routeTable": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', variables('routeTable2'))]"
                            },
                            "serviceEndpoints": [
                                {
                                    "service": "Microsoft.Storage",
                                    "locations": [
                                        "[resourceGroup().location]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                                    "locations": [
                                        "[resourceGroup().location]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "[parameters('gatewaySubnet')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('gatewaySubnetPrefix')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/providers/locks",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('virtualNetworkName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', variables('virtualNetworkName'), '-LockDoNotDelete')]",
                    "apiVersion": "[variables('locksApiVersion')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "level": "CanNotDelete",
                        "notes": "Resource Lock - Do Not Delete!",
                        "owners": []
                    },
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', variables('routeTable1'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', variables('routeTable2'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networksecuritygroups/', variables('networkSecurityGroup1'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networksecuritygroups/', variables('networkSecurityGroup2'))]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, the deployment seemed to work this morning after putting a dependsOn in, however now it's falling down again, there';s another cquestion with a conversation ongoing under the question name ""Json dependsOn ignored" that has more detail on it and also the proper complete script.. thanks for your input :)